# Фильтрация списков в angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Добрый день, подскажите, как сделать фильрацию списка в angularjs.

Есть

```
app.controller('StudentsCtrl', function($scope, $routeSegment, $http) {    
    $http.get('api/getstudents').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.Students= data;
    });
});
```

---

```
<div class="well" style= "height: 100%; overflow: scroll;" ng-controller="StudentsCtrl">
   <ul class="nav nav-list">

    <li >
    Поиск<input type="text"></input>
    </li>                                 
    <li class="nav-header">Студенты</li>

    <li ng-repeat="Student in Students" >
        <a ng-href="#">{{$index+1}}-{{Student.Fio}}- id{{Student.id}}</a>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Я хочу, чтоб пользователь вводил в поле поиск символы и сразу видел отфильтрованные данные (где Fio   1) начинается на такие же символы 2) или содержит такие символы).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внезапно, первый же пример в документации делает то, что вам нужно: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter